# Jquery $('#div').show().delay(5000).hide(); doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to show a div thats set to `display: none;` for 5 seconds with

```
$('#div').show().delay(5000).hide();
```

but it deson't work, it just goes straight to hide()

Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$('#div').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
```

By passing in numbers to `.show()` and `.hide()`, jQuery will take those methods into its internal *fx queue* (even if the number is zero). Since `.delay()` only works within a queue, you need that little workaround.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zceKN/

Comment: +1 That's slick.  Much nicer than my brute force approach to adding it to the queue.

Comment: that `hide(0)` also worked for animation. I even didn't need the delay `.animate({opacity: 0}, 400).hide(0)`

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `.queue()` because `.hide()` isn't queued by default.

```
$("#div").show().delay(5000).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).hide();
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a duration on your hide for it to work:

```
$('#div').show('slow').delay(5000).hide('slow');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/GLTaB/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#div').show();
setTimeout(function(){$('#div').hide();}, 5000);
```

.delay() works for animations only