# How do is use the SetInterval function and the 'if' to make div's pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, random, setinterval

i have this script for a Whack a mole game, but i can't seem to make my div's pop up when I want them to by using a random number generator. This is my code:(by the way this is my first game I have ever made so it's pobably a stupid question :))

```
        //minigame
setInterval(function() {
var randomnumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);  
            if (randomnumber = "1") {
                $('#mole1').show();
                };
            if (randomnumber = '2') {
                $('#mole1').show();
                };
            if (randomnumber = '3') {
                $('#mole1').show().delay(300).hide();
                };
            if (randomnumber = '4') {
                $('#mole1').show().delay(300).hide();
                };
            if (randomnumber = '5') {
                $('#mole1').show().delay(300).hide();
                };
            if (randomnumber = '6') {
                $('#mole1').show().delay(300).hide();
                };  
}, 200);
```

and my html that's relevant:

```
            <div id="minigameblockholder">
        <div class='moles' id="mole1"> </div>
        <div class='moles' id="mole2"> </div>
        <div class='moles' id="mole3"> </div>
        <div class='moles' id="mole4"> </div>
        <div class='moles' id="mole5"> </div>
        <div class='moles' id="mole6"> </div>

        <div id="scorebord"> </div>

    </div>
```

I have not started working on my scoreboard yet so don't other correcting that.
thanks in advnce,
Jasper

Comment: Moles 4-6 wouldnt work anyway, as you have them wrapped in functions that are never called. Also, your random number generator is creating 4 numbers that are never used. Does 1-3 ever work?

Comment: i have it vreate the extra numbers so that sometimes there wont be an extra mole spawned and sometimes there will be. i forgot to remove the extra functions around mole 4, 5 and 6

Comment: moles 1 to 3 also dont work as intended

Comment: if (randomnumber = "1") -> i think you should use == (comparison operator)... also, you can simplify it, a lot (no need for all that if statements)....

Comment: Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/t4keLhrb/)**?

Comment: I'm really new to jquery/javascript and I have no idea what you are typing actually means..... 
can you give me an example?

Comment: Would this also work, it would be much simpeler: $('mole'+ randomnumber).show(0).delay(700).hide(0);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit

I don't know if you edited your answer, however I can see some things that would prevent it from working.

Your if statements will not work. You are using an assignment operator ("="), this is how you assign variables.

`var x = 2;` *(assign 2 to the variable x)*

You need to use "==" (is equal to) operator in comparisons.

`if(randomnumber == 2)` *(if randomnumber is equal to 2)*

### Orignal Answer

Following on from my comment, I can't see from your codefragment why it isn't working. However, you could try something like the following;

```
setInterval(function(){
    var randomnumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    $('#mole1').html(randomnumber);

    var mole = $('#mole' + randomnumber);

    if(mole != undefined){
        $('.moles').hide();
        mole.show();
    }
}, 2000)
```

This creates a random number, attaches it to the id "mole" (eg: mole + 2) and checks to see if it is defined (exists). If it is, it hides all the other moles and shows the selected mole (in our example, 2). This will also get rid of all of the if statements and will allow you to increase or decrease the number of moles without having to create extra checks for them.

You can see it working here https://jsfiddle.net/ezs00xw0/

*Note: Ignore the extra html and css, this was for debugging purposes.*

Comment: i have one more question: why doesnt't the delay of 300 miliseconds work? because if i just sya (show()) it works but when i say (show().delay(300).hide()) it doesnt appear for the 300 miliseconds. the = -> == worked by the way thanks

Comment: No worries. What you are trying to do there is called function chaining. The delay function only works with other functions that are in a "queue", and you need a workaround to place show and hide in to that queue. You can do this by using show(0) and hide(0). This info is taken from a very good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288669/jquery-div-show-delay5000-hide-doesnt-work