# Hiding dynamically created DIV inside datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have created a datatable with a DIV that I want to hide on page load. 
Here is the div:

```
<div class="user" id="userinfo_46"><b>Name: </b>benjy corpuz<br><b>Phone Number: </b>N/A<br><b>Alternate Phone Number: </b><br><b>Email: </b>N/A<br><b>Best Time To Reach: </b>anytime<br><b>Location: </b>new yrork, NY<br><b>Case Description: </b>confidential<br></div>
```

I did try this:

```
$('.user').hide();
```

And this:

```
$(document).on("pageload", ".user",function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

But nothing. Not sure if there is another way of hiding it on load, can't use a click or such.

Here is a Jfiddle by user Hodrobond, this illustrates the problem well:

https://jsfiddle.net/fcpambdm/

I am getting answers that don't seem to understand that the element is dymanic, so it can't be hidden like a regular element.

Comment: Is the `div` existent in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) on page load, or is it created after page load? Try setting a breakpoint on the `$('.user').hide()` call, and see what you get when you examine `$(".user")`

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fcpambdm/) is a jsfiddle demonstrating a possibly simplified case of your issue. 1. Page is loaded. 2. Elements with class "user" are hidden. 3. Dynamically created table is created (including the element with class "user").

Comment: @Hodrobond I will add this to my question, totally correct what you achieved. That is exactly the problem. I have done this with clicking or such but not sure of a pageload event.

Comment: The problem is essentially "hide happens before element exists", the solution would probably be along the lines of "hide after the element exists", so we ask "when does it exist?". Are there any callbacks to the dynamic element creation? That would likely be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @Hodrobond check my answer, it is SO simple. But thanks for your help, you got the jist of the problem. Its the callback thing you mentioned that made me think of the solution thx :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, I guess I was trying to solve the wrong problem (thought there might be elements with class `user` which shouldn't be hidden), over complication on my part. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add attribute

```
style="display:none"
```

to your div element user.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution with dynamically added content (just added the delay for demonstration purpose). Also note that we need to use `hide(0)` if we intend to use `delay` [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288669/jquery-div-show-delay5000-hide-doesnt-work):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.user').append('<b>Name: </b>benjy corpuz<br><b>Phone Number: </b>N/A<br><b>Alternate Phone Number: </b><br><b>Email: </b>N/A<br><b>Best Time To Reach: </b>anytime<br><b>Location: </b>new yrork, NY<br><b>Case Description: </b>confidential<br>').delay(1000).hide(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user" id="userinfo_46">
</div>
```

**NB: shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})` is `$(function(){})`. Equivalent javascript is `$(document).ready(function(){})`**

Comment: This isn't a solution. If you can't reproduce the problem and provide a solution, leave this as a comment on the OP.

Comment: @himanshu it has to be inside a datatable not just plain HTML. It needs to be dynamically created DIV.

Comment: I understand but the OP hasn't provided any code, and I've used [jQuery DomReady](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). @JCLopez I've got the point, I'll update as soon as I've the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Totally just found the answers, its simpler than we all thought.

```
<div class="user" style="display:none" id="userinfo_46"><b>Name: </b>benjy corpuz
<br><b>Phone Number: </b>N/A
<br><b>Alternate Phone Number: </b>
<br><b>Email: </b>N/A
<br><b>Best Time To Reach: </b>anytime
<br><b>Location: </b>new yrork, NY
<br><b>Case Description: </b>confidential
<br>
</div>
```

Just added style="display:none" to the div and it will hide once the datatable loads that column. Easy :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
//Detects whether the DOM is ready..
$(document).ready(function(){
  //if ready, then run the ff lines..
  // ........
  //Hides the selected div container with class ".user"
   $(".user").hide();
});
</script>

<div class="user" id="userinfo_46"><b>Name: </b>benjy corpuz
  <br><b>Phone Number: </b>N/A
  <br><b>Alternate Phone Number: </b>
  <br><b>Email: </b>N/A
  <br><b>Best Time To Reach: </b>anytime
  <br><b>Location: </b>new yrork, NY
  <br><b>Case Description: </b>confidential
  <br>
</div>
```